# cannot redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a visual studio MVC project.

In a current view, I have codes in a function :

```
window.open("../Report/ReportPage.aspx");  //open a web page on a new tab and the tab is on top
var url = '@Url.Action("IndexMain", "MainController", new { id = 1 })';  //redirect to the main page
window.location.href = url;
```

The problem is that the main page is not displayed when running the function, On the current view, there is  a Back buttton that will redirect to the main page, at this point when I move the cursor to the button, the cursor shape is still a pointer not a hand. clicking on the button has no any response as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Show html of your button.

Answer (score 0):

js functions in both files.

Before redirect, I called a third party javascript function. That one opens a dialog. I believe the third party causes the problem. Once remove the third party, the redirecting works fine.

Thank you for trying help me.